# Как убирать лишнее пустое пространство в коде VS?

Tags: visual-studio

Часто возникает ситуация, когда работая в VS убрал ненужный блок кода, но всё, что внутри него сдвинуто. Можно ли быстро вернуть код в удобное для чтения состояние не прибегая к клацанию Backspace на каждой строчке?

[image: Лишнее пустое пространство после удаления блока if]

Comment: Просто переформатируйте код